# Spectral decomposition and positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

To perform spectral decomposition, do we require a matrix to be positive definite ?

Why ?

Comment: Don't see what this has to do with statistics. The answer depends on whether you would like to guarantee real-valued spectrum, for example. If you are ok with having complex eigenvalues, matrix need not be positive definite.

Comment: Every diagonalizable matrix $A$ has a spectral decomposition $A=\sum \lambda_jp_j$.

Comment: Every normal matrix can be diagonalized (so it doesn't have to be positive definite).

Comment: Ok thanks. Cos my friend said it has to be positive definite, which confused me

Answer (score 2):

Positive definiteness is sufficient, but not necessary, for a spectral decomposition. Here, I'm taking the meaning of "spectral decomposition" of a matrix $A$ to mean an expression
$$ A = \sum_{i} \lambda_i P_i $$
where $P_i$ is an orthogonal projection onto the corresponding eigenspace. Such a decomposition exists if and only if $A$ is a normal operator, and every positive-definite matrix is normal.

Comment: Hum... I see now what people call spectral decomposition: unitarily diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on which properties of the resulting spectrum you would like to guarantee. It's perfectly possible to perform spectral decomposition on a large class on non-positive-definite matrices. Consider, e.g. the matrix $\left( 0 \quad 1\\-1 \quad 0 \right)$, which has eigenvalues $\pm \sqrt{-1}$.

Usually to guarantee real-valued spectrum, or some nice properties, we consider positive definite matrices, or work with $A^T A$, which is positive definite, instead of $A$ itself...